# Drag and drop of disks in macOS Catalina

Tags: swift, macos, drag, disk, macos-catalina

I have a macOS app that used to accept drag and drop of disks as well as DMG files.
Since Catalina, it does not accept disks any more, but DMG files still work as before.
I tried full disk access, but the behavior didn't change.

Here's an excerpt of my plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>dmg</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>dmg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Shell</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>disk</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>disk</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Shell</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The code receiving the event hasn't changed and still works for DMG files:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_: Notification) {
    let event = NSAppleEventManager.shared().currentAppleEvent

    if event?.eventID != AEEventID(kAEOpenApplication) {
       NSApp.terminate(self) // in this case user used drag and app is just reaching this point after everything is set and done
    } else {
```

Any ideas?

**Update 10/27**
Turns out, I had to update a few outdated keys AND export and test via Finder vs. running via Xcode. If I tried the latter, it would not "honor" the new plist entries. Weird. Here's the update part of the plist file:

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>diskimage</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Shell</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.disk-image</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>disk</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Shell</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.volume</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: See the code above...

Comment: Is this drag & drop on the app icon in the Finder/Dock or drag & drop on a view in the app?

Comment: It's in the Finder, i.e. dragging a DMG file or disk (image) onto the app icon.

Comment: I tried your code on macOS 10.13 High Sierra and both dmg and disk don't work, `event` is `nil`.

Comment: The code won't work w/o the plist file being configured properly, which I think is my problem. It's worked for several major OS versions until Catalina. The event is not event sent to the application until the Finder recognizes the application as possible target for certain file types which is done via the plist. At least that's my theory.

Comment: Did your code and pilst work with macOS 10.13 and/or 10.14? The documentation of `currentAppleEvent` says "Returns the descriptor for currentAppleEvent if an Apple event is being handled on the current thread.". Is `applicationDidFinishLaunching` called when an Apple event is being handled? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. This is what I've been working on updating for Catalina: 
https://www.renerosendahl.com/software/software/dmgcleaner
I had to rebuild the plist file and use different entries; what didn't help was that when opening/running from Xcode it behaved differently than when exporting and running via the Finder. I'll post the updated plist file. All working now w/o code changes.